# C# MSChart Candle Stick & Moving Average Chart. Error： Formula error - There are not enough data points for the Period

Tags: c#, mschart, moving-average, candlestick-chart

You cannot vote on your own post
0

I am trying to create a stock candle with MA(15) on daily data.

I can create a chart with OHLC bar without any problem.

But when I started usingDataManipulator.FinancialFormula for MA, I keep getting errors of "Formula error - There are not enough data points for the Period."

Can someone help me out on this? Thanks

Here is the code.

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=XXX;Database=Stock;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        connection.Open();
        string sql = "Select datestamp, highprice, lowprice,openprice, closeprice from daymarketdata where tickname='GS' and datestamp>'1/1/2011' order by datestamp asc";

        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        SqlDataAdapter sa = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sa.SelectCommand = cmd;

        sa.Fill(ds, "Cos");
        connection.Close();
        chart1.Series["Daily"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;
        chart1.DataSource = sa;
        chart1.DataBind();


        chart1.Series["Daily"].XValueMember = "DateStamp";
        chart1.Series["Daily"].YValueMembers = "HighPrice, LowPrice, OpenPrice, ClosePrice";
        chart1.Series["Daily"].IsXValueIndexed = true;

        chart1.Series["Daily"].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        chart1.Series["Daily"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        chart1.Series["Daily"].CustomProperties = "PriceDownColor=Green, PriceUpColor=Red";
        chart1.Series["Daily"].XValueType = ChartValueType.Date;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = 100;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 180;
        chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.MovingAverage, "15", "Daily", "MA");
```

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 1-2 point in your series? Moving average needs a minimum of values to be computed...

Comment: As I said, "I can create a chart with OHLC bar without any problem."  When I added the MA formula, it shows that errors.  I have over 3000 data point showing.

I also have tried converted the date to datediff("1/1/2011") so the x-axis is number isstead of date. same error.

I ignore the first 15 period using filters as well, still same errors.   

I have no idea why this error shows up.

Answer (score 3):

Although pretty old I thought I leave my contribution since I was struggling with the very
same error message and the posted code actually pointed me in the right direction.

I believe the chart1.DataBind() needs to move after setting XValueMember and YValueMembers. Like so:

```
    chart1.Series["Daily"].XValueMember = "DateStamp";
    chart1.Series["Daily"].YValueMembers = "HighPrice, LowPrice, OpenPrice, ClosePrice";   
    chart1.DataBind();
```

by the time the FinancialFormula gets applied the data will not have been loaded into the series object otherwise.
You may run into other issue though ;)

Answer (score 1):

please add

Chart1.DataManipulator.IsStartFromFirst = True