# MS Chart,C# dotnet

Tags: asp.net, mschart

Hello i want to make candle chart using MS chart control and want to make it real time as per current time.i am done with stored procedure and also get real time data of high,Low,open,close etc.. from database and want to set this in chart so how is it possible....?Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this to get data from stored procedure into the DataTable.

```
public static DataTable GetData()
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection("someConnectionString");
        conn.Open();
        var comm = new SqlCommand("GetData", conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someParameter", someParameterValue);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        var dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        comm.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
        return dt;
    }
```

Then you can bind it to the chart:

```
var dataTable = GetData();
Chart1.Series[0].DataSource = dataTable;
Chart1.Series[0].DataBind();
```

`Series[0]` must have `ChartType` set to `Candlestick` and your stored procedure needs to return 4 numbers for each row. I don't remember now what is the order but probably: open, close, min, max. You can check this by trying or in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer does not reply the question in full. Author asks about binding candlestick chart, which is more complex case because is has four Y data channels. I encountered the same problem and found good discussion on another question [C# MSChart Candle Stick & Moving Average Chart. Error： Formula error - There are not enough data points for the Period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261691/c-sharp-mschart-candle-stick-moving-average-chart-error-formula-error-ther). I recommend the code there to anybody interested in the subject.